# IE8 inner html and tag object properties

Tags: jquery, html, dom, internet-explorer-8

I have some kind of trouble in my code in IE8.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<li></li>
</div>


<script>
var $container = $('.container');
$('li', $container).get(0).my_plugin_inited = true;

alert($container.html());

</script>
```

So I put some property to object of DOM element 'li' and fetching whole html code. In normal browsers all what I will get is just

```
<li></li>.
```

BUT, this is IE...
So now I'm getting

```
<LI my_plugin_inited="true"></LI>
```

and it's clearly disappointing me. What I can do, how should I save properties in DOM objects to do not crash DOM HTML code? I tried jQuery prop() but it didn't work out.

Comment: Don't put LI elements directly inside DIV's. LI's should be inside UL's...

Comment: Btw why are you serializing the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$( 'li' , $container ).data( 'my_plugin_inited', true );
```

Read here: http://api.jquery.com/data/

---

Btw you could do this:

```
$( 'li' , $container )[0].dataset.my_plugin_inited = true;
```

but `dataset` is not implemented in IE.

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dataset